# How can I install the Redmine emails Reminder plugin on EC2?

Tags: redmine, reminders, ec2-ami

I already have a Redmine instance running on EC2, on Ubuntu.
Now I want to install the Redmine Reminders via email, on my EC2 instance.
How can it be done?
Many Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I used this and worked to me!

http://redminecrm.com/boards/4/topics/448-installing-redmine-2-2-passenger-nginx-rvm-on-ubuntu-12-04

Don´t forget to update and update apt-get before follow this tutorial